# how do I determine if a JS file is AMD-compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, amd, curl.js

I'm using `curl` or `require` (evaluating both) to load js files asynchronously. I'm using 5 js files in my prototyping app:

```
jquery.min.js // off of CDN
Bacon.js // reactive programming tool
curl.js  // js loader
index.coffee // page specific
foo.coffee // app specific
```

OK, so I built `index.coffee` and `foo.coffee`, so I'm pretty sure those aren't AMD compatible. Could be wrong though, since `foo.coffee` has

```
if module? && module.exports?
  module.exports = Foo
```

at the end.

How do I look at a js file and say 'Yes, AMD' or 'No, not AMD'?

Comment: By AMD do you mean Advanced Micro Devices?  The CPU manufacturer?

Comment: @SteveWellens Asynchronous Module Definition

Comment: @SteveWellens The tag wiki helps in this case.

Comment: +1 for trying CurlJS. Somehow over the last 2 years of using AMD pattern, I completely migrated to CurlJS. RequireJS was a (load timing) mess in 1.x times.

Comment: Hey jcollum, try the AMDjs tag instead of AMD. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `define(` signature of AMD.  That's a *fairly* sure bet.  It can be almost anywhere in the file, unfortunately.  It's typically at the top or the bottom.  There are many variations of AMD modules and several UMD module formats, too: https://github.com/umdjs/umd and https://gist.github.com/unscriptable/4118495.

Fwiw, you can use raw CommonJS modules with curl.js, as well.  You have to place your CJS modules into a folder and tell curl that it's a package that uses CJS modules:

```
curl.config({
    packages: [
        { name: 'foo', location: 'path/to/foo-folder', main: 'foo',
            config: { moduleLoader: 'curl/loader/cjsm11' }
        },
        { name: 'curl', location: 'path/to/curl/src/curl', main: 'curl' }
    ]
});
```

You need the curl package (or a path) to tell curl where to find curl/loader/cjsm11.

Answer (score 0):

AMD means, that you evaluate code as you need to, not at the moment it loads. So if your code executes right after downloading - it's not AMD. If it has a wrapper around it, allowing the code to be executed by demand - it can act like AMD module.

If you're looking for [exact AMD API](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD), you should search for `define` word at the beginning of your file.

Comment: If it has `}).call(this);` at the end, that's not AMD then?

Comment: No, if what's inside that brace is executed right away. All compiled coffeescript is wrapped in such braces with `call(this)` in the end, question is what's inside them.